# Get exact last filled row number in an excel file that has is associated with a complex formula using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

A complex formula is applied to a column till end of the excel sheet.but when I'm retrieving the last row number using Sheet.getLastRowNum() 
it is returning last row of the sheet though the excel sheet is having only 10 rows.Is there any way get the exact last filled row in the excel file even if 
formula applied to end of the excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

From http://affy.blogspot.cz/2004/04/poi-optimization-eliminating-trailing.html
Retrieve required formula then use this code. it will remove all those empty rows and then you can get required data with your data retrieving code.

```
List yourlist = new ArrayList();
        String value = null;
        FileInputStream inputStreams1 = null;
        inputStreams1 = new FileInputStream(FileNameWithPath);
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStreams1);
        HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

        boolean stop = false;
        boolean nonBlankRowFound;
        short c;
        HSSFRow lastRow = null;
        HSSFCell cell = null;
        HSSFRow FirsttRow = null;

        while (stop == false) {
            nonBlankRowFound = false;
            lastRow = (HSSFRow) sheet.getRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());
            for (c = lastRow.getFirstCellNum(); c <= lastRow.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
                cell = lastRow.getCell(c);
                if (cell != null && lastRow.getCell(c).getCellType() != HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    nonBlankRowFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (nonBlankRowFound == true) {
                stop = true;

                yourlist =  yourMethod(FileNameWithPath, sheet); //updated HSSFSheet object which will have 10 rows
                /*use this code to remove all those empty rows then use hsheet object. now use this hsheet object will
                 have only non empty rows(in your case 10 rows)*/

            } else {
                sheet.removeRow(lastRow);


            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks Sonal. It is not suitable to my case because my excel file is having 10000 rows and 400 columns  among only first  10 rows are filled. and formula is appiled to 50th column in the sheet so in this case getLastRowNum() returns 10000 and going back to 10th row is a performance issue in my case.Is their any other suitable solution for this scenario?